# Forward all received calls to sender address on destination chain using lxly Ethereum<--->zkEvm

Tags: polygon-bridge, zkevm

So I have to build a contract that sends all calls to the sender's address on the other network. Functionally, this will allow erc-6551 contracts to call one or the other instance on another chain. Direction: Ethereum - > zkEVM (using the LxLy bridge)
I would like to have your opinion on the best way to implement it.
I have some experience using the LxLy bridge and message layer of PolygonZkEVMBridge i just need some logic implementing the bridgeMessage and the onMessageReceived function of my forwarder